# Button wont work in all tabs

Tags: c#, button, tabs

I cant find my specific problem.

I have an windows application in c# build it with couple of friends to learn the language it self one of  my friends being at an hardware it education and knowing one teacher teaches programming he asked if he had some kind of a group based training exorcise and this is what we got.

We need to build a windows app for an classic model sales company.

now my problem is that i need to do the employees section of it and every thing except the buttons (they work but not in all tabs)  is working.

I have 2 buttons and 3 tabs A tab summary a tab details(where the buttons are pleased)and a mutation tab where we can edit the selected employee. my problem is that the buttons work in some kind of strange way in the summary the buttons will move the selected row back and forward but in the details and mutation tabs they will not do any thing.

```
private void btnback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index >= 1)
    {
        int rowIndex = Math.Min(
                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index - 1, 
                dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1);
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = 
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex]
                .Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
    }    
}

private void btnnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index  <= 1)
    {
        int rowIndex = Math.Min(
                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1, 
                dataGridView1.Rows.Count +1);
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex]
            .Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
    }    
}
```

can some one please point me in the right direction in what i have done wrong so i can fix it and we can put all the separate pieces together to make the full application.

Comment: is dataGridView1 only on the summary tab?  You will have to check which tab is active and then you can put code in to affect whichever grid is active on that tab.

Comment: the grid is indeed on de summary screen the other 2 screen are mainly build of text boxes where al the data of the selected row needs to be put in.

Comment: you need to pull the selected row data key and use that to load the other controls.  that code can be placed right at the bottom of each of the button clicks.

Comment: Another problem i came across now is i also have a searchbox that needs to search for a row that matches the search valve, i am a begining programmer and can you point out what or where i can vind the row data key

Comment: whatever column has the unique key for the row, just pull that cell using the columnindex.

Comment: there where some code changes tried that one out but even then there is nothing hapening in the grid the buttons wont go futher then row 3and nothing happening in the onther 2 tabs. just for the heads up evry column is unique the database exept for the last and first name columns is designed in such a way that for example the column empnumber cant have the same nummber twice

Comment: ok i see no one can help me with this problem thats a shame for me